# How to add a percentage to top of Column chart in C#

Tags: c#, charts

So, here's the problem.

I have a chart that displays two columns, Completed and Uncompleted, across a number of work types, using the following loop:

```
foreach (var workType in model.WorkTypes)
        {
            decimal completed = 0;
            decimal uncompleted = 0;
            decimal workSubmitted = 0;
            decimal completionRate= 0;
            foreach (var rec in model.JobList.Where(x => x.jobType== workType.Id))
            {
                uncompleted += model.JobList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.recID== rec.recID && x.jobType == workType.Id).Uncompleted;
                completed += model.JobList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.recID == rec.recID && x.jobType == workType.Id).Completed;

            }
            workSubmitted = uncompleted + completed;

            if (uncompleted != 0)
            {
                completionRate= (completed/ workSubmitted) * 100;
            }                
            myChart.Series["Uncompleted"].Points.AddXY(workType.TypeName, uncompleted );
            myChart.Series["Completed"].Points.AddXY(workType.TypeName, completed);
        }
```

What I am trying to do is have it display a label above the two columns that displays the completionRate value as a percentage for each workType.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

This is the current look of the chart:
[image]

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `Labels` show the y-value but you can set an arbitrary `Label` for each `DataPoint` e.g. when you add the point like this:

```
int p = myChart.Series["Uncompleted"].Points.AddXY(workType.TypeName, rejections);
myChart.Series["Uncompleted"].Points[p].Label = sometext;
```

And of course you can calculate the text for the label as needed, e.g.:

```
string sometext = (workSubmitted / rejections * 100).ToString("0.00") + "%";
```

Note that you must update the `Label` after changing the values in your calculation. No automatic expressions are supported!

**Update**

As I wrote, placing a `Label` **centered** at the x-value the columns share, is hard or even impossible; that is because a `Label` belongs to an individual data point. This is a unique problem with column (and bar) type charts, since here the points of the series are displayed in **clusters** around the common x-value. (We could workaround if and only if we had an **odd** number of series by adding the labels to the mid points)

So we need to use `Annotations`. Here is a function that will place a `TextAnnotation` centered at the x-value and at the height of the larger y-value of two data points..:

```
void setCenterAnnotation(Chart chart, ChartArea ca, 
                         DataPoint dp1, DataPoint dp2, string lbl)
{
        TextAnnotation ta = new TextAnnotation();
        ta.Alignment = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        ta.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        DataPoint dp = dp1.YValues[0] > dp2.YValues[0] ? dp1 : dp2;
        ta.Height = 0.36f;
        ta.AxisX = ca.AxisX;
        ta.AxisY = ca.AxisY;
        ta.AnchorDataPoint = dp;
        ta.AnchorX = dp1.XValue;
        ta.Text =  lbl;
        chart.Annotations.Add(ta);
}
```

If you have more than two `Series` you would best determine the anchorpoint, i.e. the one with the larger value before, and pass it instead of the two points I pass here..

Placing/anchoring annotations is not really obvious, so here are a few notes:

- I **anchor** to a `DataPoint` to make it show at the height of its y-value.
- To use (axis-)values for anchoring one has to assign one or both axes to it.
- I **then** (order matters!) set the `AnchorX` property so that it is not centered over a point but over the common x-value.
- I also set some `Height` or else the text won't move up on top of the column; not quite sure what the rationale is here..

Here is the result:

[image]

I had added the anotations while adding the points:

```
int ix = s1.Points.AddXY(i, rnd.Next(i+7));
s2.Points.AddXY(i, rnd.Next(i+4)+3);
double vmax = Math.Max(s1.Points[ix].YValues[0], s2.Points[ix].YValues[0]);
string lbl = (vmax / 123f).ToString("0.0") + "%";
setCenterAnnotation(chart12, ca, s1.Points[ix], s2.Points[ix], lbl );
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps somewhat, but I am not looking to put it to the top of either the completed or uncompleted, but on top of the overall group.

Comment: What is the 'overall group' ? Can you show an image of what you  have and what you want?

Comment: I've added a picture with the circled areas.

Comment: OK, this, unfortunately is a lot harder than one would wish. Atm I can't think of a better solution than adding TextAnnotations; I'll post an update when I got it working..

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.

Comment: One last question, when I am performing the .AddXY, I am assigning a text value to those that equates to the 'work 1', 'work 2', etc, that I had in my example, rather than a numerical index.

How would I use that text value to retrieve the index needed to pass to your function? I tried just using a counter value but it clusters all the labels at on the left of the chart.

Comment: This is a common mess you've got yourself in. There are ways around but the recommended one is to use a numerical x-value. You can still assign an individual text to each DataPoints's AxisLabel.

Comment: - If you really want to stick to non-numerical x-values you should first understand that the x-values are lost and all point have zeroes instead(!!). You can still find a point from its label, maybe like this `var hiz = chart1.Series[0].Points.Cast<DataPoint>().Where(x => x.AxisLabel == labelString).ToList();` (maybe not unique) or find the index from a point via `int ix = chart.Series[0].Points.IndexOf(dp1);` but there is no guarantee that this will actually be a valid x-value to dock the annotation to.

Comment: Note that I have changed the way to add points a bit to show how to use an index `ix`