# Set series name as Axis X position

Tags: c#, winforms, bar-chart

I have bar char like this:

[image]

As you can see I have eight series name I generate like:

```
    foreach (var item in allProjectsModel.Where(x => x.TaskName != "Overall"))
            {
               graphTasksCompleted.Series.Add(item.TaskName);
               graphTasksCompleted.Series[item.TaskName].Points.AddXY(item.TaskName, currentHours);
            }
```

But as you can see I only have one value of my series name on x Axis and I want each one by corresponding color like this:

[image]

Why it only display one if I use `TaskName` as `XValue`? Regards

I also tried using:

```
 graphTasksCompleted.Series[item.TaskName].Points[0].AxisLabel = item.TaskName;
```

But I get same result

Comment: because there only is __one__ x-value. you can use normal labels, which will display on top of each column.

Comment: How can I use normal labels? can you help me there? and there is more than one x value, because it is changing into foreach (item.TaskName) @TaW

Comment: You can set the Labels for each point as you set the AxisLabels. - The x-values __are__ all the same for the clustered points. And if they were added as strings they all are `0` anyway. If you knew the positions you could use CustomLabels, but you don't. The only way I know of are TextAnnotations. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226629/how-to-add-a-percentage-to-top-of-column-chart-in-c-sharp/52227389?s=1|0.0000#52227389) for an example. You would need to modify the y-values to a value of 0 minus something to place them under the axis and you would omit the centering offset.